# Indesign: show the first and last page number of a chapter in footer

Tags: pagination, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to use InDesign to revamp a scientific magazine published by my course in college. Until now, everything was done by hand using Microsoft Word.

The problem that stumped me is this: I need to show, in every chapter's footer, a line of text like this:

```
Tríade - Sorocaba, v. <issue number>, ed. <edition number>, <chapter title>, <number of the page the chapter started>-<number of the page the chapter ends> -- <month>/<year>.
```

So, in Chapter One, titled "Hello World", spanning from page 10 to page 15, the footer would like this:

```
Tríade - Sorocaba, v. I, ed. II, Hello World, 10-15 -- April/2017.
```

In Chapter Two, titled "It's me", pages 16-25, the footer would change to this:

```
Tríade - Sorocaba, v. I, ed. II, It's me, 16-25 -- April/2017.
```

As I've said, in the last issues, we did everything by hand, editing everything, but InDesign should make everything a lot smoother, except I can't find a way to make this footer to work. I scoured the manual, but there is only the "last page" variable, that shows number of pages from the entire document. There is no set variable that shows the first and last page numbers from each chapter. How can I do this in InDesign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Last page variable:**
Text > Variable > Define > Modify "Last page"
Select "Section" as range instead of document.

**First page of section:**
a little bit trickier:
Create a hyperlink text destination on the first page of the
section, then cross-reference it in your
Master page footer, which can be set to show only the page number.

Comment: I'm sorry for the long time before answering. In the end, I implemented half of your answer. The Last Page was spot on, but the hyperlink + cross-reference was a little bit awkward as page moved around, so in the end I decided to do this:

I created a new Running Header Variable to show the first text which implements the PageMarker character style. Then, I changed the PageMarker to show invisible text, and added on the first page of each section a special character with the current page number using that style. And that's it.

Thank you for your answer!